# Dimension of an angle

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, si-units, absolute-units

Usually angles are described as dimensionless, justifying this by saying that they can be viewed as length divided by length. 
As a student of mathematics I'm asking myself wether this is a convention or an unavoidable fact.
I think that angles could be given the same dimension of length if for example we assign to a given angle the length of the arc on which it insists in a circumference of radius one unit length centered in the vertex... in this definition there is no division (not even implicit).
I have heard voices (in class) that there is no coherent system of dimensions. I hope that this is not true (is it?)... Anyway, is it possible to have a system of dimensions as coherent as the one is commonly used where angles aren't dimensionless?

NOTE: The measure of an angle (as the measure of any quantity) comes from the relation with a fixed angle taken as a unit. I think that I can define one radiant or one degree or my other unit arbitrarily and then measure all my angles with this unit. There is no god's law or postulate of physics that force me to say they are dimensionless. I think it's just a matter of conventions. If you do not agree, please show the postulate or the god's law!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33595/discussion-on-question-by-lanzariel-dimension-of-an-angle).

Answer (score 2):

The definite mathematical definition of dimension is as follows.
Suppose there is a mathematical (geometrical) quantity $A$, which may be dependent of the scale $l$. If after a scale transformation:
$$l\rightarrow \lambda l, $$
the quantity would transforms as
$$A\rightarrow \lambda^{n}A.$$
Then the quantity $A$ has dimension $n$.
According this definition, the length has dimension 1, the are has the dimension 2, the volume has dimension 3, etc. And the angle has dimension 0.
Note that according this definition, the dimension does not need to be integer which is indeed the case of fractal geometry.

Comment: Thank you for showing us the double meaning of dimension. What we are talking about can be found here:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis P.S. The definition of Hausorff dimension I saw was quite different...

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It _could_ easily be expanded to answer the questio, but as it's currently written, I don't think it does.

Answer (score 2):

Remember first that the *only* thing you need to define a circle is the radius: a circle is all the points that are the same distance from a given point, and that distance is what we call the radius.

So if the only thing that defines a circle is a radius, what's the difference between two circles? Well, we only have one feature to work with, and it only has one characteristic, length. So the only possible difference between two circles is the length of the radius. The radius of a circle is a physical quantity: you can measure it with a meter stick or a piece of string. It's not an arbitrary thing that you decide after the fact. So in order to differentiate a smaller circle from a larger circle, you have to give the radius units. You can't set *all* the radii equal to 1, otherwise someone could come along with a meter stick, measure two of your circles, and work out that 3 meters = 5 meters and then we really start to have trouble with the math.

Another consequence of the geometry of circles is that the circumference is rational with the radius: there are always 2π times as many length units around the outside as there are from the center to the edge. It doesn't matter if your circle is the size of a dime or the size of a galaxy, that relationship is always the same. So when talking about circles you can naturally throw out meters or feet or light years and use the radius as the length unit, and call it a radian. Now you can describe the circumference as 2π radians for all circles, using radian as your "dimensional" unit.

But we're stuck again, because radians can be different lengths so we still need meters to say what a radian is. Otherwise all circles are the same size, and I really don't want to order a pizza the size of Jupiter of play golf with a ball the size of a raindrop.

So when we go to describe a given angle, let's say a full circle just to keep it simple, we can say that all full circles are 2π radians around, but to tell one from another we have to say *what size radian* so that'll be in meters, and then since the circumference was "measured" in radians to begin with, that is in meters as well, and when we describe traveling so many meters *around* for each meter *out from center* it turns into dividing meters by meters and we're dimensionless again.

Comment: 1) Sorry for being fussy but I'm facing a delicate yet fundamental topic, so I want to be rigorous. Units are not **necessary** to differentiate a smaller circle from a larger circle. This differentiation can be also done using the Euclidean concept of rigid-transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation) and the notion of being _inside_ a circle. With units you can do it but it's not the only way you have of doing it, therefore we can not say that units are **necessary**, we can say that they are **sufficient**.
2) I have never said I would like all the radii equal to one.

Comment: 3) "there are always 2π times as many length units around the outside as there are from the center to the edge. It doesn't matter if your circle is the size of a dime or the size of a galaxy, that relationship is always the same." This is exactly my point. I can say that in my system to measure angles I **don't** take a random circle. I take the circle that has radius one. Fixing the radius I don't have a ratio but I have a length since I do not need to do any division.

Comment: Now I see the problem. Changing between units would change the amplitude of angles.

Comment: Ok, I'm not giving a valid alternative to dimensionless angles.
Let's just say I invent a new dimension. I call this the radian. And I use it to measure angles.
Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @lanzariel there's nothing wrong with measuring angles in radians, we do it all the time. I just hope you realize by now that the length of the arc tells you nothing about the angle *without* knowing the radius length, even if you "fix" the radius by setting it equal to 1rad, and that if you do that the circumference must be in radians as well and then you again get a dimensionless value. There's literally no way to get a dimensionful angle because the geometry of an angle is naturally and necessarily dimensionless.

Comment: @DavidWhite,
Please, don't be so superficial.
I have never said I have a valid alternative, nor I know the answer. I'm asking why angles are dimensionless and if it would cause troubles to assign them a dimension.
Do you know the answer? Please write it!
If you don't know it, please don't close this discussion.

Comment: @Asher
I knew this before. I do work with radians with no problem at all!
I don't get why there is no way to get a dimensionful angle.
Like when I measure length I take one meter or whichever unit I want and I compare it with the length I want to measure, the same can be done with angles, taking one radian or one degree for example (described geometrically) as my unit.
The problem is that I couldn't multiply length by angle obtaining length, we have just to change the formula we use to get the arc length. Are there deeper problems due to the fact that now angles have dimension?

Comment: @lanzariel , several of the previous answers have already answered your question.  The angle is represented by the arc length divided by the radius, which must necessarily be a dimensionless number, whether you call it degrees or radians or something that you decide to make up.  I suggest you stick to the math stack exchange, where you can ignore dimensions and units to your heart's content.  Correct physics absolutely REQUIRES dimensional consistency, or it is just plain WRONG, and there is no debate about this from anyone who knows any substantial physics.

Comment: @DavidWhite, did you read my comments? **I know the usual definition!** I would like to know if we can have dinensional consistency giving angles some dimension! Of course we have to **change the usual definition!** If we can't, please, tell me when we will enncounter errors! I don't want to ingnore dimensions, I want to know how dimensional consistency works!

Comment: @lanzariel, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis

Comment: @DavidWhite could you quote the relevant part, please?

Answer (score 0):

Individual angles provide trigonometric RATIOS (as their functions).Ratios are dimensionless.

Comment: My point is: What if I change DEFINITION?

Comment: Then show us an example of how you change the definition

Comment: Why don't you just read the question? "I think that angles could be given the same dimension of length if for example we assign to a given angle the length of the arc on which it insists in a circumference of radius one unit length centered in the vertex... in this definition there is no division (not even implicit)." Please, don't consider me a stupid because I'm asking you a question on something you find easy. It is NOT so easy. I'm not asking why this system works, but whether this is the only coherent possible system or not.

Comment: You need two lengths to describe an angle on a circle. The radius and the section of the circumference. You merely set one of the lengths equal to 1. However, it is still a length and division is still implicit.

Comment: So, is it the only possible coherent system?

Answer (score 0):

Typically angles are measured in degrees, with 360 degree in a circle. That is completely arbitrary. Less so is when the angle is measured in fractions of a circle - radians. With 2 Pi radians in a circle.

Comment: What you say is irrelevant to dimensional analysis...

Answer (score 0):

Notice, angle is a dimensionless quantity. In the context of 2-D Geometry, the angle is a ratio i.e. a dimensionless quantity given as $$\text{plane angle at the center of circle}=\frac{\text{arc}}{\text{radius}}$$

In the context of 3-D Geometry, the solid angle given as

$$\text{solid angle at the center of sphere}=\frac{\text{surface area}}{\text{(radius)}^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

While you make a very narrow definition, it fails to be useful.

> I think that angles could be given the same dimension of length if for
>   example we assign to a given angle the length of the arc on which it
>   insists in a circumference of radius one unit length centered in the
>   vertex..

Fine. So for some angle of a unit circle we define angle in terms of the length of the included circumference. Excellent. Angle now has the dimension of length.

But now take an identical circle/angle combination and change its diameter. Let's take a 2 meter circle. For the same angle, the included circumference is twice that of the unit circle. So units of length don't work.

In fact, by specifying an included circumference for a circle of a specified diameter, you are implicitly forming a ratio: the ratio of the circumference to the diameter (or radius, I'm not picky). In order for the angle to be constant for similar shapes of varying sizes the included circumference must be scaled to the diameter, and this scaling is, by its nature, making use of a ratio.

Comment: Ok. So my counter-example does not work. Yet this is not sufficient to show that dimensionless angles are the only coherent choice

Comment: What if we invent a dimension just for the angles?